# Oracle - Group By Having - Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

So my knowledge of Oracle is limited and I am wanting to improve it. But I am stuck;

```
SELECT c.parent_id 
  FROM x.atable c
  JOIN y.anothertable e
    ON c.obj_id = e.child_id
 WHERE e.child_type = 'G'
 ORDER BY c.PARENT_ID
```

This comes with results

```
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
```

What I want to do, is group by, but only the ones where more than 1 result occurs (so results 2 and 3).

So I did this

```
SELECT c.parent_id 
  FROM x.atable c
  JOIN y.anothertable e
    ON c.obj_id = e.child_id
 WHERE e.child_type = 'G'
 GROUP BY c.parent_id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT c.PARENT_id > 1)
 ORDER BY c.PARENT_ID
```

But I don't quite understand what's wrong with my query. As I said, I am not the most experienced with SQL, so an explanation would be nice. I get it at the "having count" section. I know my group by is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paranthesis is in the wrong place

```
SELECT c.parent_id FROM x.atable c
JOIN y.anothertable e
ON c.obj_id = e.child_id
WHERE e.child_type = 'G'
GROUP BY c.parent_id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT c.PARENT_id) > 1
ORDER BY c.PARENT_ID
```

Comment: Oh so THAT'S what it means. Thanks very much.